# answers.ros question: seeing responses to my questions

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a better way for me to navigate to my most recent question to see answers? The list in my profile seems to be in some random order, so I have to do an exhaustive search. I must be missing something!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298915/answers.ros-question:-seeing-responses-to-my-questions/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a better way for me to navigate to my most recent question to see answers?

Do you not get the red envelope at the top of the page next to your account name? That should show you there are responses to your questions (which could also be edits or comments):

[image: image description]

Also: if you have configured a proper email address you should get email notifications if/when responses have been posted to your questions.

> The list in my profile seems to be in some random order

it should not be not random actually, but sorted by the number of upvotes your questions received, followed by the date the last answer was posted on.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-07-29**:
Ah, that tiny red thing is an envelope! I do have it but it was so small that I tended to not even try to click it. But I just discovered the followed tab, which seems even better. I assume that I automatically “follow” My own questions And sorted by upvotes? Not obvious and not so useful imo.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-29**:\

> But I just discovered the followed tab, which seems even better

not for seeing what the latest responses to your own questions are.

The followed tab is just a listing of questions you follow. This comment (posted by me) won't show up there. It will show up on your *notifications* tab.